# Send csv file through REST in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I have to send .csv file to remote server through REST in rails.

I had tried post_form of Net::HTTP and made form as multipart true, by this file get transfer (seen in parameters at both side) but at server side i am not able to read it.

It gives error "No such file or directory."
Please any can tell me is there other way to transfer file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding on this and tried many things i got good solution from that i can send csv file by REST web service.
here is solution...

https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty

Also can use REST Client for testing purpose.